# Simplest way to construct a string by interpolating values into a Regex pattern?

Tags: regex, string, .net-3.5

I usually end up with a lot of conditions and/or loops to parse a regex and interpolate values back into its capture groups, and am looking for experienced answers to solve this problem in hopefully a simple manner.

For example, given a regex pattern like `X(?<xid>\d+)-(?<xsub>\w+)\.xml` having the named capture groups "*xid*" and "*xsub*", intended to match filenames like: **X1-foo.xml**, **X555-bar.xml**, etc, when provided with the arguments: `int xid=999, string xsub="baz"`, I want to interpolate those values into the pattern groups to construct the proper filename:  **X999-baz.xml**

To keep it simple, explicit captures are not nested.

---

**Without String.Format**:

This concept is easily accomplished with .NET String format items like `String.Format("X{0}-{1}.xml", xid, xsub)` however I already have a Regex pattern to parse out those values from any filename string, and want to use the same pattern to go in the opposite direction by reconstructing a filename with it, for accuracy.  If I require a regex pattern to parse values from a string, but a string with format items to reconstruct the filename, it requires two kinds of distinct syntaxes to be used, creating a greater chance of manual error when writing them - it's too easy to mistakenly create a bad format item string that does not properly reconstruct the result of a regex pattern match, or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex (yay, meta-regexes!):

```
public static string RegexInterp(Regex pattern, Dictionary<string, string> pairs) {
    string regex = pattern.ToString();
    string search;

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in pairs) 
    {
        // using negative lookbehind so it doesn't match escaped parens
        search = @"\(\?<" + entry.Key + @">.*?(?<!\\)\)"; 
        regex  = Regex.Replace(regex, search, entry.Value);
    }

    return Regex.Unescape(unescaped);
}
```

And then:

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"X(?<xid>\d\d+)-(?<xsub>\w+)\.xml");

var values = new Dictionary <string, string>() {{"xid", "999"},
                                                {"xsub", "baz"}} ;

Console.WriteLine(RegexInterp(rx, values));
```

Prints

```
X999-baz.xml
```

**Demo: http://ideone.com/QwI2W**

Answer (score 0):

I may have read this wrong but it sounds like you need the Regex.Replace method in the System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace.

```
string pattern = "Your pattern";
string replacement = "Your text to replace";
Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);
```

There are other methods in the regex library that might better accomodate multiple replacements in a single string.

Comment: In this situation, the regex is in fact the `input`.